# GWT Selenium Tests sometimes fails

Tags: dom, gwt, selenium, selenium-webdriver

we currently have a nice problem with our selenium tests in a gwt powered gui.

The application contains two sections (filter and grid). Our tests sometimes fails with a NoSuchElementException.

Crazy is the following: I stop the test in eclipse with a breakpoint and inspect the page with firefox firebug or any other addon. And okay - I cannot find the desired element. But (without restarting the application or any other changes in eclipse), if i try again and search the element it is there and a resume in eclipse the test goes green. For me it seems like a synchronize problem in firefox.

A explicitly wait command

```
new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10).until(condition);
```

has the only effect, that the timeout (10 seconds) happens.

As I said - sometimes the test is green and sometimes it fails.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you load some data asynchronous (RPC) from the server? The data and thus the element which presents the data in the UI is not there yet, when Selenium is looking for it. Depending on how long your queries take on the database or what latency you have on the network the wait time may vary from test-run to test-run.

Comment: Hello Adrian. You are right! The element in the DOM is replaces during a async rpc execution. That is why we use the explicit wait statement (see in my question). The condition in this statement is somthing like "return true when element 'xy' is in the DOM. In the meantime I found a quick and dirty workaround...

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this problem and would share this.
The following piece of code is executed before the explicit wait command is running.

```
Window window = getDriver().manage().window();
Dimension dimension = window.getSize();
Dimension tmp = new Dimension(dimension.getWidth() - 1, dimension.getHeight());
window.setSize(tmp);
window.setSize(dimension);
```

I figured out, that the DOM is in "synchronized" state after the browser window is resized. So I decrement the width and than set it back to the old value.

If anybody has a better suggestion - let us know ;-)